# Cardinality of a family of subsets of $\mathbb N$ having finite symmetric difference.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ be such that $A,B\in \mathcal F\implies A\Delta B$ is finite,where $\Delta$ denotes the symmetric difference .Can the set $\mathcal F$ have the cardinality $c=|\mathbb R|$?

I am stuck with this problem and need some hint.

Comment: Fix $A\in \mathcal{F}$, and consider the map $f\colon \mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, sending $B\mapsto A\Delta B$.

Comment: @tkf how does that help?

Comment: What do you know about the image of $f$? Can you show that $f$ is injective?

Comment: @tkf I can show $f$ to be injective.Let $f(B)=f(C)$ then $A\Delta B=A\Delta C$.This implies $A\cap B=A-(A\Delta B)=A-(A\Delta C)=A\cap C$.

Comment: Let $x\in B$ .If $x\in A$ then $x\in A\cap B=A\cap C\implies x\in C$.

Comment: If $x\notin A$ then $x\in B-A\subset A\Delta B$,which implies $x\in A\Delta C$

Comment: So, $x\in (A-C)$ or $x\in C-A$ but $x\notin A\implies x\notin A-C$,so $x\in C-A$ which implies $x\in C$,thus $B\subset C$

Comment: By symmetry, $C\subset B$.

Comment: So,we have shown that,$B=C$

Comment: @tkf now what?...............

Comment: Image of $f$ contains all finite subsets of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Very good - just one thing about the last comment - it should be the other way round: The Image of $f$ is **contained** in the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Now how many finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are there?

Comment: Also a shortcut you could use for your proof of injectivity: If $f(B)=f(C)$ then $A\Delta B=A\Delta C$ so $$B=A\Delta(A\Delta B)=A\Delta(A\Delta C)=C.$$ However what you wrote is perfectly good too, so you can stick with that if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting an answer by summarizing the discussion in the comment,

Fix $A\in \mathcal F$

Define $\phi:\mathcal F\to \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ by $\phi(B)=A\Delta B$

$\phi$ is injective as $\phi(B)=\phi(C)=A\Delta B=A\Delta C\implies A\Delta (A\Delta B)=A\Delta (A\Delta C)\implies B=C$.

So,$|\mathcal F|=|\phi(\mathcal F)|$

Now note that $\phi(\mathcal F)\subset \mathcal P_{\text{finite}}(\mathbb N)$,the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb N$.

$|\mathcal F|\leq \aleph_0$.

Comment: Yes exactly (+1).